# could not find or load main class - Error when run through Command prompt

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I know there are similar questions posted before and I went through those but still its not working for me.

I am creating a sample JMS test class (chat application) and uses javaee.jar and javax.jms.jar. I can test it through Eclipse IDE and it works fine. But I am trying to run through command prompt so I can run multiple windows.I managed to compile the Chat.java file and it created the Chat.class. But when i try to run it, I get `could not find or load main class`. These are the commands I used:

From the `src/domain` folder:

`javac -classpath javaee.jar;javax.jms.jar Chat.java`---- this created Chat.Class inside domain folder where domain is the package name

The I ran the following command from `src` folder

`java -classpath javaee.jar;javax.jms.jar domain.Chat` ---- this gives me the `could not find or load main class domain.Chat` error message

But when I run without the -classpath parameter(`java domain.Chat`), it reads the main() and gives me different error since it cant find the jms jar files.

`E:\eclipse\Spring\JMSChat\src>java domain.Chat
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageList
ener`

So basically it finds the `Chat.class` file when I don't pass in the classpath parameter and it cannot find the class when I use the classpath to add the jars. I tried running it from within domain folder as well as from src folder, but no luck. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have your tried adding `.` to the classpath ie `-classpath .;javaee.jar;javax.jms.jar`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Now its picking up the class file but still throws the NoClassdefFoundError:javax/jms/MessageListener

Comment: Where are the jars located?  Try adding the pull path to them in the class path...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Ok so now I placed the 2 jar files (javaee.jar and jms.jar) under src folder and its working. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure that's a good idea, but your at least moving in the right direction...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I know. But now I get new errors such as it cant locate the ConnectionFactory parameters configured in GlassFish server.I am not sure how to map those values through command prompt. It's working in Eclipse. so whatever..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
java -classpath javaee.jar;javax.jms.jar;. domain.Chat
```

By default `java` uses the current directory in the classpath. When you use the `-cp` flag, it does not so the path to `domain.Chat` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can run multiple instances of the app from Eclipse, and you can check their outputs by cycling through their allocated consoles by clicking on the arrow next to the console icon

2) try running from your source folder `java -classpath .;javaee.jar;javax.jms.jar domain.Chat` "." means current dir